# cPanel/WHM - Assign cron jobs to specific account package automatically

Tags: php, cpanel, cronjob, whm

I would like to know if it's possible to, when creating an account in a specific package, automatically assign cron jobs to run in it.

Example:

I've created the account "example", wich is in package "super_cool", so automatically this account will have a cron job to, let's say, execute a PHP script everyday at 00:00 AM

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more what this php script is supposed to be doing? And isn't it possible to use the root account to access the other sites and plan just one cronjob that does whatever you want to do on all sites by default? Keep in mind that if you made a cronjob on user level, they can remove that cronjob as well.

Comment: Hello LPChip! I use this simple script: https://github.com/VisualAppeal/PHP-Auto-Update, wich is a auto-update system, where I just have to run "update/index.php" file on the website I want to update and it checks for a new version on the main server. I would like to set up this index.php to run everyday 00:00AM, and preferably make it not user accessible, because as of now anyone who accesses "update/index.php" will trigger a website update, if available

Comment: Sounds like the solution you thought of for your problem is not the right one. You do not want to create a cronjob for each account, because that means the user always has access to the php file, but instead you want the main account to run the cronjob and check for all user accounts and update those.

Comment: I see. So, there's a way to set root to run the update command for all the accounts? The file will have to be trigerred individually in each account for it to update, is it possible? Can it be done in only one account package type? thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I just did a check on my account, and it seems I am unable to actually access /home/ where all the accounts are stored. I don't know if you have that access, which you wouldn't if you are on a virtual server that has accounts not owned by you (shared hosting). If you do have access to the /home directory, you need to process all the accounts through there.